Movement continues for diagonal movement after releasing one key
For example, if I press W key and D key, that would produce a movement in the Northeast position. However, if I release either key (meaning I am holding only W or D at the moment), the movement still continues going northeast when I want it to go east if it is D only, and north if it is W only. However, if I release both of the keys and then press either W or D it works perfectly.
The code for my main CharacterBody2D:
extends CharacterBody2D
class_name Player

var x_input: float = 0.0
var y_input: float = 0.0
var pause_lock: bool = false

@onready var sprite = $PlayerSprite
@onready var f_arm = $PlayerSprite/Torso/R_Arm
@onready var b_arm = $PlayerSprite/Torso/L_Arm
@onready var hand = $PlayerSprite/Torso/R_Arm/Hand
@onready var aim_pivot = $PlayerSprite/Torso/AimPivot
@onready var fsm = $FSM
@onready var leg_anim = $LegsAnimation

@export var MAX_SPEED       : int = 50
@export var ACCELERATION    : int = 1000
@export var FRICTION        : float = 1.0

@export var base_hp         : int = 0
@onready var hp: int = base_hp

var motion : Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO
var direction : Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO

func _player_input():
    x_input = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    y_input = Input.get_action_strength("move_down") - Input.get_action_strength("move_up")
    
    direction = Vector2(x_input, y_input).normalized()

func _idle():
    motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0.0, FRICTION)
    motion.y = lerp(motion.y, 0.0, FRICTION)

func _move(delta, direction):
    motion += direction * ACCELERATION * delta
    motion.x = clamp(motion.x, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
    motion.y = clamp(motion.y, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
    
    print(motion)
    velocity = motion
    move_and_slide()

func aim(pos: Vector2):
    _flip_player_sprite(pos.x < self.global_position.x)
    if (pos.x < self.global_position.x):
        f_arm.rotation = lerp_angle(f_arm.rotation, -(aim_pivot.global_position - pos).angle(), (0.10))
    else:
        f_arm.rotation = lerp_angle(f_arm.rotation, (pos - aim_pivot.global_position).angle(), (0.10))
    b_arm.look_at(hand.global_position)

func _flip_player_sprite(flip: bool):
    match flip:
        true:
            sprite.scale.x = -1
        false:
            sprite.scale.x = 1

func _animate_legs():
    if (direction == Vector2.ZERO):
        leg_anim.play("Idle")
    else:
        var is_forward: bool = (
                (sprite.scale.x == 1)
                or (sprite.scale == Vector2(-1,1) and x_input < 0)
        )
        
        match is_forward:
            true:
                leg_anim.play("Walk_Forward")
            false:
                leg_anim.play("Walk_Backward")

The code for the finite state machine attached as a child:
extends Node

enum STATES {IDLE, MOVE}

var state: int = 0

@onready var parent = get_parent()


func _physics_process(delta):
    run_state(delta)


func run_state(delta):
    parent._player_input()
    parent.aim(parent.get_global_mouse_position())
    
    match state:
        STATES.IDLE:
            parent._idle()
            
            if (parent.direction != Vector2.ZERO):
                _set_state(STATES.MOVE)
        STATES.MOVE:
            parent._animate_legs()
            parent._move(delta, parent.direction)
            
            if (parent.direction == Vector2.ZERO):
                _set_state(STATES.IDLE)


func _set_state(new_state: int):
    if (state == new_state):
        return
    
    state = new_state


You're only zeroing your motion variable when both x and y inputs are zero, not when a single one of them drops to zero.

Sorry, could you specify around which part about the motion variable?

In func _idle, motion.x = lerp(... (and likewise for y) is the only line that ever reduces motion toward zero. The code in func _move just adds input to it. If the input drops to zero on one axis, adding zero won't reduce the value motion already holds on that axis.

Thank you! I realise the problem now. The problematic part was the motion += direction * ACCELERATION * delta



func _move(delta, direction):
    if direction == Vector2.ZERO:
        if velocity.length() > (FRICTION * delta):
            velocity -= velocity.normalized() * (FRICTION * delta)
        else:
            velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    else:
        velocity += (direction * ACCELERATION * delta)
        velocity = velocity.limit_length(MAX_SPEED)
    print(velocity)
    move_and_slide()



Had to some lines of code.

Chunks of code like this are rarely good answers; what part of it fixes the issue described in the Question?
